# SQL Server: BCP queryout fail

Tags: sql-server

This code works well

```
USE BellariaNetAssets
DECLARE @printFile VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT ip FROM fnMuninCfg()
```

However this code fails:

```
USE BellariaNetAssets
DECLARE @printFile VARCHAR(1000)
SET @printFile = 'BCP "SELECT ip FROM fnMuninCfg()" queryout "C:\users\aag\desktop\munin' 
+ '.cfg" -c -T -t "|" '
EXEC xp_cmdshell @printFile
```

The errors are:

> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'fnMuninCfg'.
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to resolve column level collations
>   BCP copy out failed

Might a good soul explain to me why the BCP affirms that the object name is invalid? The function appears to be OK (code #1).

Comment: Use 3-part names in your query: `SELECT ip FROM YourDatabase.dbo.fnMuninCfg();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try fully qualifying the function name (e.g. Adventureworks.dbo.fnMuninCfg())

My guess is that when you are calling it, I believe that xp_cmdshell runs in the context of the master db and so when you call an unqualified function, it is by default looking in the master db for your function.  Let me know if it works!